# Jquery bind function to dynamically created upload control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an upload control

```
<div id=bodyContent>       
    <input  id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple  /> 
</div>
```

created server side.
This control is used by the following function:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        //Do Something
    }
})
```

Now, this control is dynamically created using javascript :

```
$('div[id *= bodyContent]').append(' <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" 
   multiple /> ');
```

I've tried to dynamically bind the function as shown below without success. I am not used to do this type of conversion, any help on that would be appreciated.

```
$('div[id*=bodyContent]').on('fileupload', 'input[id*=fileupload]', function ({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
         //Do Something
    }       
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: `fileupload` is not an event..

Comment: _this control is dynamically created using javascript_ add the code that create it.

Comment: The fileupload control is added to the page through an append: $('div[id *= bodyContent]').append(' <input  id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple  />  ');

Answer (score 2):

The `id` should be unique in same document so try to replace it by class attribute, the after every append init your `fileupload` :

```
$('<input class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>').appendTo
   ('div[id*="bodyContent"]').each(function() 
{
    initFileUpload();
});

function initFileUpload()
{
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            //Do Something
        }
    })    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried your solution, it still doesn't work if the control is dynamically created, it works if the control is created on server side.

Comment: Ok try my update it should work with dynamically created element.

Comment: Thanks for this solution it works perfectly, I'm glad we managed to talk the same language, thanks again. Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else said, fileinput is not an event that is emitted by input elements. You want to watch for either the 'input', or 'change' event

Comment: the fileupload function is from an api,  the fileupload widget listens for change events on file input fields. This widget can be found here:/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */